# Determine Image Rotation in HTML Javascript

Tags: html, css, image, rotation

I developed a web app that allows users to take a picture on their phone or tablet and upload it using a `input type="file"` element.  The users can take photos using either orientation on their mobile device.

Somehow, when you open the image in the web browser by pointing to its URL directly, it appears with the correct orientation.

[image: upright]

But, in my app when it is in an `img` tag with the `src` pointing to the URL it is rotated.

[image: rotated]

I know I can use CSS `tranform` to rotate the image.  The problem is that I don't know how to tell if the image is rotated or not.  How does the browser know to rotate it when navigating directly to the URL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check out exif.js then you grab the orientation tag...thats what I'm facing right now...but I wanted it to permanently orient it...i don't know if that is possible but at least with display, you'll be able to do that.

http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/